# Tableview swipe in iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, uislider, swipe-gesture

Hi I'm new to iOS Development.  I want to design something similar to Groupon app for iPhone.
I need 4 or 5 table views (each table view is a category which lists the products in that category )which I can slide or swipe through like in the Groupon app.

I'm confused on whether I should have all the table views in one page view which can be swiped through or one page view per table view.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried either?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have to thought about what you would prefer? You can have an index page with buttons leading to tableview for each category or you can an index page consisting of a tableview of the categories. Touching a specific item in the tableview can lead to another tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) does exactly what you need:

> A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of
>   content, where each page is managed by its own view controller object.
>   Navigation can be controlled programmatically by your app or directly
>   by the user using gestures. When navigating from page to page, the
>   page view controller uses the transition that you specify to animate
>   the change.

Here is a very nice tutorial on how to implement it:
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the link to the tutorial.  It is very helpful.